# Help me on using map() function() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make array of ids of all DIVs using the below code,

```
var srcs = $.map($('div'),function()
{
  return this.prop('id');
});
alert(srcs);
```

Below is my HTML code..

```
<div id='d1'></div>
<div id='d2'></div>
<div id='d3'></div>
<div id='d4'></div>
```

Here is the fiddle link,
http://jsfiddle.net/HcL82/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var srcs = $.map($('div'), function(obj) {
    return $(obj).attr('id');  
});
```

Comment: Note that you can replace the return statement with `return obj.id;`

Answer (score 4):

`.map()` is applied to a selector; like this:

```
var ids = $('div').map(function(){
  return this.id;
});

console.log(ids); // ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
var srcs = $('div').map(function(){
     return $(this).prop('id');
   }).get();
alert(srcs);
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using get() here.. Thanks

Comment: The get() converts the returned values to a basic array. You may not need that part. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
var srcs = $.map($('div'),function(n,i)
   {
     return $(n).prop('id');
   });
alert(srcs.join(','));
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/MpkLs/

Comment: What makes difference if I use join() in this scenario. Thanks

Comment: Join flattens the array and returns a string with each array element value separated by the character that is passed into the 'join' function. I used it at then end of this example just to demonstrate that everything had worked as it should via the value in the 'alert' statement. You wouldn't need to use 'join' to do what you wanted.